# Can't access object in jquery (prevObject?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A function in my WP plugin has just randomly (as far as I can tell) stopped working.

Here's the code in question:

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        var classes = jQuery('img',html).attr('class');
        var items = classes.split(" ");
        ... more stuff here
}
```

I've confirmed that the *html* variable is indeed an *img* html tag. Here's what firebug shows when I do a console.log of the object (**console.log(jQuery('img',html));**):

```
Object[]
context -> undefined
jquery -> "1.11.2"
length -> 0
prevObject -> Object[img.alignnone.size-full.wp-image-1234 name.jpg]
```

And the error it shows is ***classes is undefined***.

I figure there's something wrong with the object I get, but this used to work recently and I'm not aware of any changes in the site that could have caused this.

I'd appreciate any input on this.

EDIT:

**More info.** This happens with two plugins which are supposed to be unrelated (made by different people). It happens when, after uploading an image to the server (or selecting a previously uploaded picture) you try to insert it into the post.

As I said before this error has appeared out of nowhere, it was working as intended a couple days ago. The only thing I can think of that has changed since then is the domain name, but I can't see how that could be related.

Comment: If the outer element of `html` is an `img` you will need to use `filter` instead of `find` to select it.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? I'm not using `find` (AFAIK).

Comment: You're using a contextual selector which is the equivalent of `find`. Try this instead: `var classes = jQuery(html).filter('img').attr('class');`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with contextual selectors. I've tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work :/ .

Comment: It would help if you also shared your relevant HTML in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this; the key was parsing the `html` string variable into proper HTML, using `jQuery.parseHTML()`. Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 2):

The `jQuery` selector always returns a `jQuery object`, but when the `length` is `0` then no elements were found matching the selector that you provided. In your example you've confirmed that nothing is selected as the `length` of the jQuery object is `0`. Perform a check whether an element was selected like this:

```
var $els = jQuery('img',html),
    classes;
if ($els.length) {
    classes = $els.attr("class");
}
```

Keep in mind that your DOM query is limited by what you pass in as the html parameter. If you simply want to find the images on the page do: `var $els = jQuery('img');`

Comment: But it does find an image! If you look at the code that shows on firebug if I do a console.log of the element, it shows a prevObject Object[img.alignnone.size-full...]. Those are the classes I'm trying to access.

Comment: @mustieles What are you passing as context? The second parameter limits the context of the search.

Comment: You mean the html parameter? This is an exact copy (minus the domain name) of the result of console.log(html): `<img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/0.jpg" alt="" width="460" height="327" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3573" />`

Comment: @mustieles It's a string then? The context should be an element: context
Type: Element or jQuery
A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Comment: @mustieles I believe what you're trying to do is `$(html)`, rather than `$('img', html)`.

Comment: I guess it's a string, yeah? But it was working just the other day, I don't get it. Is there any way that I can turn this into a jQuery element?

Comment: Using `$(html)` doesn't throw the same error but it doesn't work either (the image doesn't get attached to the post).

Comment: @mustieles $(html) <- this creates the element, $(html).appendTo(post); <- this will create it and attach it.